# JavaScript function doesn't wait for file system operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

I'm trying to create a simple JS function which reads the directory, loop over all the files inside that DIR and push information in the array. So console.logs regarding file data do output the correct data, but  console.log({response}) at the end of the newFunc function doesn't output anything neither does the getFileData from awaited async function. However I've also tried to put timeout on the called async function which results in the correct returned response (this means JS doesn't wait for my file read to finish it's work).

Functionality meantioned above:

```
const newFunc = async () => {
  let response: any = [];
  fs.readdir("files", function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Could not list the directory.", err);
      process.exit(1);
    }

    for (const file of files) {
      fs.stat(`files/${file}`, (err, stats) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }

        // print file information
        console.log(`File Data Last Modified: ${stats.mtime}`);
        console.log(`File Status Last Modified: ${stats.ctime}`);
        console.log(`File Status Last Modified: ${stats.size}`);
        console.log({ file });
        response.push({
          fileName: file,
          updatedAt: stats.mtime,
          createdAt: stats.ctime,
          size: stats.size,
        });
      });
    }
  });
  console.log({ response });

  return response;
};
```

NodeJS endpoint functionality:

```
  const getFileData = await newFunc();
  console.log({getFileData})
  res.status(200).json(getFileData);
```

Comment: you might need to use `readdirSync` instead of `readdir` taking into account your current implementation

Comment: do you maybe know what should be used instead of fs.stat since it looks like it should be awaited as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `readdirSync` and `statSync` functions. This way the code will wait for the response from the function calls. Currently, due to async nature of `fs.readdir` and `fs.stat` methods the code doesn't wait and logs empty response array while also returning an empty response.

Your newFunc method should look like this:

```
const newFunc = async () => {
  let response: any = [];
  try {
    const files = fs.readdirSync('files');
    for (const file of files) {
      const stats = fs.statSync(`files/${file}`);
      console.log(`File Data Last Modified: ${stats.mtime}`);
      console.log(`File Status Last Modified: ${stats.ctime}`);
      console.log(`File Status Last Modified: ${stats.size}`);
      console.log({ file });
      response.push({
        fileName: file,
        updatedAt: stats.mtime,
        createdAt: stats.ctime,
        size: stats.size,
      });
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  }
  return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`readdir` and `stat` are async operations so it seems that in `newFunc` you are returning the value of `response` not waiting for these async operations to complete. So, you could use [`readdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreaddirsyncpath-options) and [`statSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsstatsyncpath-options) instead of `readdir` and `stat` or you could probably just add an `await` in your current implementation in front of the `fs.readdir` and `fs.stat` calls.